# Limit of the series $\sum{a_n}$ where $a_n= \frac{1}{n}$ if $n$ is a square and $\frac{1}{n^2}$ otherwise

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Recently I have stumbled upon a question like this-

> $$a_n = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n} \ \mbox{ if } n \mbox{ is a perfect square} \\ \frac{1}{n^2} \ \mbox{ otherwise}, \end{cases}$$
>   Comment on the convergence or divergence of the series $\sum{a_n}$.

I am not sure but I thought like this-
$$\sum{a_n} =\\(1+\frac{1}{4} +\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{25}+...)<2(1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{9}+...)<\infty$$
Thus $\sum{a_n}$ converges. But  I am not sure if the steps are correct or not. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I think you understood the key point of the solution, but as you wrote it, this is not very rigourous .

Comment: @nicomezi can you please tell me how to prove this rigorously ? I kept on doubting myself :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make your idea rigorous, we can let $k$ be the largest integer so that $k^2\leq N$. We have
$$ \sum_{n=1}^Na_n<\sum_{n=1}^k\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n^2}<2\sum_{n=1}^N\frac1{n^2}. $$
Now, use that the RHS converges.

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative, consider
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n &= \sum_{n=1} \left(\frac{1}{n^2} - a_n\right) \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \begin{cases} \frac{1}{n^2} - \frac{1}{n} & \text{if $n$ is a perfect square} \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} \\
&= \sum_{m=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{m^4} - \frac{1}{m^2}\right) \\
&= \zeta(4) - \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^4}{90} - \frac{\pi^2}{6}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} - \left(\frac{\pi^4}{90} - \frac{\pi^2}{6}\right) = \frac{\pi^2}{3} - \frac{\pi^4}{90}.$$

Comment: (+1) Same answer I got: $2\zeta(2)-\zeta(4)$.

Answer (score 3):

The set of perfect squares greater than $1$, $S$, is enumerated by $\{ k^2, k \in \mathbb{N}^* \}$ (not difficult to prove if required), then :

$$\sum_{n \in S} \frac 1 n = \sum_{k\ge 1} \frac 1 {k^2}.$$

Then :

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} a_n = \sum_{n \in S} a_n + \sum_{n \notin S} a_n < \sum_{k \ge 1 } \frac 1 {
k^2} + \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac 1 {k^2} = 2 \sum_{k \ge 1} \frac 1 {k^2} <\infty$$